# get timestamp from datetime value using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my RoR app, a table gets created in this way:

```
class CreateEmailMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :email_messages do |t|
      t.string :recipient
      t.string :subject
      t.text :text
      t.text :html
     t.string :status
      t.belongs_to :owner
      t.text :data
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
...
end
```

later on, I try to access the created_at field using:

```
    <td>
      <%= email_message.created_at %>
    </td>
```

however this only returns a date.
how I can get the **timestamp**?

in the database, the field i'm looking for looks like this:

```
2011-11-10 19:16:59.056382
```

i've even added this:

```
config.active_record.record_timestamps = true
```

but still no luck.
how I can get the **timestamp** with the date?

Comment: What version of rails? created_at is a datetime by default for me

Comment: what kind of DB? if you look at the row in a query browser is it definitely only storing the date?

Comment: postgres 9.1. "timestamp without timezone". the timestamp is definitely in the database. it's just being dropped when it's displayed in the html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `<%= email_message.created_at.to_s(:db) %>`
or one of the other to_s format options listed here:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/to_s#311-Full-List-of-Supported-Formats